# Amazon S3 - How to perform CRUD operations?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using Backbone.js for my project. My question is, how to perform CRUD operation in amazon S3? so far I can upload/create files into bucket and retrieve files but I don't know how to do update and delete files.

config.php

```
<?php
//Bucket Name
$bucket_name ="my_bucket";

//include the S3 class
if (!class_exists('S3'))require_once('S3.php');
            
//AWS access informations
if (!defined('awsAccessKey')) define('awsAccessKey', 'access_key');
if (!defined('awsSecretKey')) define('awsSecretKey', 'secret_key');
            
//instantiate the s3 class
$s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

//this is used to create a bucket in amazon S3
$s3->putBucket($bucket_name, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
?>
```

upload_image.php

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST'); 
    
    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']) && isset($_POST['productId'])) {
        
        //upload file formats
        $valid_file_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg","PNG","JPG","JPEG","GIF","BMP");
        function get_file_extension($file_name) {
            return substr(strrchr($file_name,'.'),1);
        }

        $filename = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
        $tmp_filename = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'];
        $filetype = strtolower($_FILES['uploadfile']['type']);
        //get file extenstion to verify the format
        $extension = get_file_extension($filename);
        
        if(in_array($extension,$valid_file_formats)){
            //include config.php
            include_once "config.php";
            //set content type in headers inorder to display image in browser
            $header = array('Content-Type' => $filetype);
            //change filename 
            $new_file_name = "w3_".time().".".$extension;
            
            if($s3->putObject(S3::inputFile($tmp_filename), $bucket_name , $new_file_name, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ, array(), $header) ){
                $img = "http://".$bucket_name.".s3.amazonaws.com/".$new_file_name;
                // array for JSON response
                $response = array();
                // check for required fields
                
                    $productId = $_POST['productId'];
                    $imageLink = $img;
                    // include db connect class
                    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
                    // connecting to db
                    $db = new DB_CONNECT();
                    // mysql inserting a new row
                    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_images(productId, imageLink,dateCreated) VALUES('$productId', '$imageLink',NOW())");
                    // check if row inserted or not
                    
                    if ($result) {
                        // successfully inserted into database
                        $response["success"] = 1;
                        $response["message"] = "Image successfully uploaded.";
                        // echoing JSON response
                        echo json_encode($response);
                    } else {
                        // failed to insert row
                        $response["success"] = 0;
                        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";
                        // echoing JSON response
                        echo json_encode($response);
                    }
                

                echo "1-".$img;
            } else {
                echo "2-Upload Failed";
            }

        } else {
            echo "3-Not a Valid Format";
        }

    } else {
        echo "4-Please Select a File";
    }

    ?>
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the php sdk
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html
There is commands there for deleteMatching to remove items from a bucket.

As for update, call putObject again to overwrite the file.